# Call a webview as child Container in multi screen App in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, webview, hybrid-mobile-app, webview-flutter

I have Multi screen app contains a bottom navigation bar, i need a page as webview as child container.
App is working fine but Webview is not loading by Container
I know we need to replace the **Container** by **WebViewWidget** but how will the other app page work?

**See below code for Dashboard Screen**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class DashboardScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  DashboardScreenState createState() => DashboardScreenState();
}

class DashboardScreenState extends State<DashboardScreen> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      getValues();
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  late final WebViewController controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = WebViewController()
      ..loadRequest(
        Uri.parse('httpa://my-domain.com'),
      );
  }
  // @override
  // Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  //   return Stack(
  //     children: [
  //       WebViewWidget(
  //         controller: controller,
  //       )
  //     ],
  //   );
  // }

  late var pages = [
    new DashboardHomeFragment(controller: controller),
    new AccountFragment(),
    new PortfolioFragment(),
    new ProfileFragment(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      //    backgroundColor: const Color(0xff101324),
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        // backgroundColor: Color(0xFFB4C56C).withOpacity(0.0),
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xff00022e),
        elevation: 4,
        title: Image.asset(
          'assets/images/logo-horizontal.png',
          height: 40,
          width: 150,
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(child: pages[_selectedIndex]),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Currency',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_balance_wallet),
            label: 'Account',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.work),
            label: 'Portfolio',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            label: 'MyProfile',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: const Color(0xff3ACCE1),
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        showUnselectedLabels: true,
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xff2c2f40),
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**See below code for Webview Screen**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class DashboardHomeFragment extends StatefulWidget {
  const DashboardHomeFragment({required this.controller, super.key});

  final WebViewController controller;
  @override
  State<DashboardHomeFragment> createState() => DashboardHomeFragmentState();
}

class DashboardHomeFragmentState extends State<DashboardHomeFragment> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xff0a0b37),
      body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        widget.controller
          ..setNavigationDelegate(
            NavigationDelegate(
              onPageStarted: (url) {
                print('Page started loading: $url');
              },
              onPageFinished: (url) {
                print('Page finished loading: $url');
              },
              onNavigationRequest: (navigation) {
                final host = Uri.parse(navigation.url).host;
                if (host.contains('youtube.com')) {
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    SnackBar(
                      content: Text(
                        'Blocking navigation to $host',
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                  return NavigationDecision.prevent;
                }
                return NavigationDecision.navigate;
              },
            ),
          )
          ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted);

        return Text("data finding!");
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Advance Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

I found the alternative solution by just trying to load the webview in same screen instead of calling another screen.

Step 1. remove the other page of the webview from **List**

```
late var pages = [
    new DashboardHomeFragment(controller: controller), // this One 
    new AccountFragment(),
    new PortfolioFragment(),
    new ProfileFragment(),
  ];
```

by below

```
late var pages = [
    new WebViewWidget(controller: controller), // Modify
    new AccountFragment(),
    new PortfolioFragment(),
    new ProfileFragment(),
  ];
```

Step 2. Add **setNavigationDelegate** and **setJavaScriptMode** from other screen to this screen.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = WebViewController()
      ..loadRequest(
        Uri.parse('my-domain.com'),
      ); // Add setnavigateDelegate and Javascript
  }
```

with this

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = WebViewController()
      ..loadRequest(
        Uri.parse('my-domain.com'),
      )
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onPageStarted: (url) {
            print('Page started loading: $url');
          },
          onPageFinished: (url) {
            print('Page finished loading: $url');
          },
          onNavigationRequest: (navigation) {
            final host = Uri.parse(navigation.url).host;
            if (host.contains('youtube.com')) {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(
                  content: Text(
                    'Blocking navigation to $host',
                  ),
                ),
              );
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
        ),
      )
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted);
  }
```

But your answers will most welcomed if you can solve this by calling the Another screen.